java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libreact_featureflagsjni.so" not found
I was manually upgrading a react-native app from 0.67.2 to 0.76.2 (making changes in the required files).  I was able to build the android app successfully after a day of debugging here and there. But when I tried to install it and run it, it throws the following runtime error. I've looked into the intermediates folder, but this file is not available. Then I've disabled the new architecture and hermes engin and tried to run. But that throws java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libjscexecutor.so not found"
Thanks in advance for your help
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libreact_featureflagsjni.so" not found
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1081)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1003)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1765)
        at com.facebook.soloader.nativeloader.SystemDelegate.loadLibrary(SystemDelegate.java:24)
        at com.facebook.soloader.nativeloader.NativeLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLoader.java:52)
        at com.facebook.soloader.nativeloader.NativeLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLoader.java:30)
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:869)
        at com.facebook.react.internal.featureflags.ReactNativeFeatureFlagsCxxInterop.<clinit>(ReactNativeFeatureFlagsCxxInterop.kt:28)
        at com.facebook.react.internal.featureflags.ReactNativeFeatureFlagsCxxAccessor.override(ReactNativeFeatureFlagsCxxAccessor.kt:505)
        at com.facebook.react.internal.featureflags.ReactNativeFeatureFlags.override(ReactNativeFeatureFlags.kt:334)
        at com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint.load(DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint.kt:46)
        at com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint.load$default(DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint.kt:32)
        at com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint.load(Unknown Source:3)
        at com.companyId.appId.MainApplication.onCreate(MainApplication.java:73)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1316)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7711)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleBindApplication(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2478)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:230)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:319)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8919)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:578)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1103)


Output of npx react-native info
System:
  OS: macOS 15.1
  CPU: (8) arm64 Apple M1
  Memory: 139.67 MB / 8.00 GB
  Shell:
    version: "5.9"
    path: /bin/zsh
Binaries:
  Node:
    version: 18.19.0
    path: ~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.19.0/bin/node
  Yarn:
    version: 1.22.22
    path: ~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.19.0/bin/yarn
  npm:
    version: 10.2.3
    path: ~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.19.0/bin/npm
  Watchman:
    version: 2024.11.18.00
    path: /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
Managers:
  CocoaPods:
    version: 1.16.2
    path: /opt/homebrew/bin/pod
SDKs:
  iOS SDK:
    Platforms:
      - DriverKit 24.1
      - iOS 18.1
      - macOS 15.1
      - tvOS 18.1
      - visionOS 2.1
      - watchOS 11.1
  Android SDK:
    API Levels:
      - "23"
      - "24"
      - "27"
      - "28"
      - "30"
      - "31"
      - "32"
      - "33"
      - "34"
    Build Tools:
      - 28.0.2
      - 28.0.3
      - 29.0.2
      - 30.0.2
      - 30.0.3
      - 33.0.0
      - 33.0.1
      - 34.0.0
      - 34.0.0
    System Images:
      - android-31 | Google Play ARM 64 v8a
      - android-33 | Google APIs ARM 64 v8a
      - android-33 | Google Play ARM 64 v8a
    Android NDK: Not Found
IDEs:
  Android Studio: 2023.2 AI-232.10300.40.2321.11567975
  Xcode:
    version: 16.1/16B40
    path: /usr/bin/xcodebuild
Languages:
  Java:
    version: 17.0.13
    path: /Users/abibv/.jenv/shims/javac
  Ruby:
    version: 2.6.10
    path: /usr/bin/ruby
npmPackages:
  "@react-native-community/cli":
    installed: 15.1.2
    wanted: ^15.1.2
  react:
    installed: 18.2.0
    wanted: 18.2.0
  react-native:
    installed: 0.76.2
    wanted: ^0.76.2
  react-native-macos: Not Found
npmGlobalPackages:
  "*react-native*": Not Found
Android:
  hermesEnabled: true
  newArchEnabled: true
iOS:
  hermesEnabled: false
  newArchEnabled: true


android/build.gradle
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 31
        compileSdkVersion = 34
        targetSdkVersion = 34
        ndkVersion = "26.1.10909125"
        kotlinVersion = "1.9.0"
        reactNativeArchitectures = ["armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a", "x86", "x86_64"]
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.2")
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.9'
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion")

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

def REACT_NATIVE_VERSION = new File(['node', '--print',"JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync(require.resolve('react-native/package.json'), 'utf-8')).version"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim())

allprojects {
  configurations.all {
      resolutionStrategy {
        // Remove this override in 0.66, as a proper fix is included in react-native itself.
        force "com.facebook.react:react-native:" + REACT_NATIVE_VERSION
        // 
        force "com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.5"
      }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        mavenCentral {
            // We don't want to fetch react-native from Maven Central as there are
            // older versions over there.
            // content {
            //     excludeGroup "com.facebook.react"
            // }
        }
        google()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}

android/app/build.gradle
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "com.facebook.react"
apply plugin: "com.google.gms.google-services"
apply plugin: "com.google.firebase.crashlytics"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation. If none specified and
 *   // "index.android.js" exists, it will be used. Otherwise "index.js" is
 *   // default. Can be overridden with ENTRY_FILE environment variable.
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // https://reactnative.dev/docs/performance#enable-the-ram-format
 *   bundleCommand: "ram-bundle",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: true,  // clean and rebuild if changing
    hermesCommand: "../../node_modules/react-native/sdks/hermesc/%OS-BIN%/hermesc",
    buildCommand: 'ram-bundle',
]

// apply from: "../../node_modules/@react-native/gradle-plugin/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = true

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

/**
 * The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore.
 *
 * For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
 * `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`
 *
 * The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data
 * allowing to use e.g. `Date.toLocaleString` and `String.localeCompare` that
 * give correct results when using with locales other than en-US.  Note that
 * this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default.
 */
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

/**
 * Whether to enable the Hermes VM.
 *
 * This should be set on project.ext.react and that value will be read here. If it is not set
 * on project.ext.react, JavaScript will not be compiled to Hermes Bytecode
 * and the benefits of using Hermes will therefore be sharply reduced.
 */
def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", true);

/* get keystore password from OSX keychain */
// def getPassword(String currentUser, String keyChain) {
//    def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
//    def stderr = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
//    exec {
//        commandLine 'security', '-q', 'find-generic-password', '-a', currentUser, '-s', keyChain, '-w'
//        standardOutput = stdout
//        errorOutput = stderr
//        ignoreExitValue true
//    }
//    //noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
//       stdout.toString().trim()
// }

// get password
// def pass = getPassword("appKey","android_keystore")


/**
 * Architectures to build native code for in debug.
 */
def nativeArchitectures = project.getProperties().get("reactNativeDebugArchitectures")

android {
    namespace 'com.companyId.appId'
    ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion

    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.companyId.appId"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 14
        versionName "1.1.1"
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk true  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            if (nativeArchitectures) {
                ndk {
                    abiFilters nativeArchitectures.split(',')
                }
            }
            resValue "string", "CodePushDeploymentKey", '"<CODEPUSH_DEBUG_DEPLOYMENT_KEY>"'
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            resValue "string", "CodePushDeploymentKey", '"<CODEPUSH_RELEASE_DEPLYOMENT_KEY>"'
        }
    }

    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
            // Example: versionCode 1 will generate 1001 for armeabi-v7a, 1002 for x86, etc.
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        defaultConfig.versionCode * 1000 + versionCodes.get(abi)
            }

        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', '../../html']
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Import the Firebase BoM
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.3.1')

    // TODO: Add the dependencies for Firebase products you want to use
    // When using the BoM, don't specify versions in Firebase dependencies
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'


    // Add the dependencies for any other desired Firebase products
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available-libraries

    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    // implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation("com.facebook.react:react-android")
        // Hermes dependency (if using Hermes)
    if (hermesEnabled.toBoolean()) {
        implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-android")
    }


    implementation project(':react-native-video')

    react {
        // Needed to enable Autolinking - https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/autolinking.md
       autolinkLibrariesWithApp()

    }

    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0"

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }

    if (enableHermes) {
        // def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        // debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        // releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
        implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-android")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.implementation
    into 'libs'
}

task bundleDebugJsAndAssets(type: Exec) {
    commandLine 'node', './node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js', 'bundle', '--entry-file', 'index.js', '--platform', 'android', '--dev', 'false', '--bundle-output', "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug/index.android.bundle", '--assets-dest', "$buildDir/intermediates/res/debug"
}


// apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
apply from: '../../node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/codepush.gradle'

settings.gradle
pluginManagement { includeBuild("../node_modules/@react-native/gradle-plugin") }
plugins { id("com.facebook.react.settings") }
rootProject.name = 'AppName'

extensions.configure(com.facebook.react.ReactSettingsExtension){ ex -> ex.autolinkLibrariesFromCommand() }
includeBuild("../node_modules/@react-native/gradle-plugin")

apply from: file("../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle")


include ':react-native-video'
project(':react-native-video').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-video/android')

// include ':react-native-vector-icons'
// project(':react-native-vector-icons').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/android')
// include ':react-native-splash-screen'
// project(':react-native-splash-screen').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-splash-screen/android')
// include ':react-native-webview'
// project(':react-native-webview').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-webview/android')
// include ':react-native-image-picker'
// project(':react-native-image-picker').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-image-picker/android')
// include ':react-native-fbsdk'
// project(':react-native-fbsdk').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android')
// apply from: file("../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)

// apply from: file("../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)
// include ':app'
// includeBuild('../node_modules/@react-native/gradle-plugin')
include ':app', ':react-native-code-push'
project(':react-native-code-push').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/app')


gradle.properties
# AndroidX package structure to make it clearer which packages are bundled with the
# Android operating system, and which are packaged with your app's APK
# https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/androidx-rn
android.useAndroidX=true
# Automatically convert third-party libraries to use AndroidX
android.enableJetifier=true

# Version of flipper SDK to use with React Native
FLIPPER_VERSION=0.99.0
reactNativeArchitectures=armeabi-v7a,arm64-v8a,x86,x86_64
newArchEnabled=true
hermesEnabled=true

gradle-wrapper.properties
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.7-all.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists

MainActivity.java
package com.companyId.appId;

import android.os.Bundle;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import org.devio.rn.splashscreen.SplashScreen;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.graphics.Typeface;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {
  /**
   * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript. This is used to schedule
   * rendering of the component.
   */
  @Override
  protected String getMainComponentName() {
    return "AppName";
  }

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    SplashScreen.show(this);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  }
}


MainApplication.java
package com.companyId.appId;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.microsoft.codepush.react.CodePush;
import com.oblador.vectoricons.VectorIconsPackage;
import org.devio.rn.splashscreen.SplashScreenReactPackage;
import com.reactnativecommunity.webview.RNCWebViewPackage;
import com.imagepicker.ImagePickerPackage;
// import com.facebook.reactnative.androidsdk.FBSDKPackage;
import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost =
      new DefaultReactNativeHost(this) {
        @Override
        public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
          return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
        }

        @Override
        protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
          @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
          List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
          // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
          // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
          return packages;
        }

        @Override
        protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
          return "index";
        }

        @Override
        protected String getJSBundleFile() {
          return CodePush.getJSBundleFile();
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean isNewArchEnabled() {
          return BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED;
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean isHermesEnabled() {
          return BuildConfig.IS_HERMES_ENABLED;
        }
      };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
    if (BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED) {
      // If you opted-in for the New Architecture, we load the native entry point for this app.
      DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint.load();
    }
    ReactNativeFlipper.initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
  }

  /**
   * Loads Flipper in React Native templates. Call this in the onCreate method with something like
   * initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
   *
   * @param context
   * @param reactInstanceManager
   */
  // private static void initializeFlipper(
  //     Context context, ReactInstanceManager reactInstanceManager) {
  //   if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
  //     try {
  //       /*
  //        We use reflection here to pick up the class that initializes Flipper,
  //       since Flipper library is not available in release mode
  //       */
  //       Class<?> aClass = Class.forName("com.companyId.appId.ReactNativeFlipper");
  //       aClass
  //           .getMethod("initializeFlipper", Context.class, ReactInstanceManager.class)
  //           .invoke(null, context, reactInstanceManager);
  //     } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
  //       e.printStackTrace();
  //     } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
  //       e.printStackTrace();
  //     } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
  //       e.printStackTrace();
  //     } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
  //       e.printStackTrace();
  //     }
  //   }
  // }
}


main/AndroidManifest.xml
<manifest
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" tools:node="remove"/>

    <queries>
      <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="http"/>
      </intent>
      <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="https"/>
      </intent>
      <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="mailto"/>
      </intent>
    </queries>

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
      android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:exported="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>


I came across the same error today. It turns out I missed the step of moving MainApplication.java -> MainApplication.kt in the React Native upgrade helper.
The Kotlin onCreate method contains this line, which I believe is responsible for loading the missing dll
SoLoader.init(this, OpenSourceMergedSoMapping)

After adding it the error went away

I solved it by:
navigate to MainApplication.kt file
add this line at top:
import com.facebook.react.soloader.OpenSourceMergedSoMapping

then update onCreate function:
 override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    SoLoader.init(this, OpenSourceMergedSoMapping)
    if (BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED) {
      load()
    }
  }

